# Java - jar with external libraries

Tags: java, jar, executable

I'm using in my program an external `jar` so I can work with `SQL` libraries, but when i do the 'clean and build' to create the executable `jar`, in the dist folder the the `lib` folder is created along with the `jar`, and if I move the main jar alone out of the dist folder, it won't open. I tried to modify the `build.xml` so that I could do the `package-for-store`, which works fine on my computer, but the jar won't open if I give it to anyone else.

Comment: Do you mean *run* instead of *open*??

Comment: Well, the program has the GUI, that's why I said 'open' the jar.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: I see. Even then, *open* sounds a bit strange. We never say open an exe or open a .sh do we?

Comment: I'm using NetBeans

Comment: Open a terminal window or command window, change to the directory containing your .jar file, and do `java -jar myprogram.jar`.  Edit your question and paste the console output into it.